# Pyparsing - where order of tokens in unpredictable

Tags: python, pyparsing

I want to be able to pull out the type and count of letters from a piece of text where the letters could be in any order.  There is some other parsing going on which I have working, but this bit has me stumped!

```
input -> result
"abc" -> [['a',1], ['b',1],['c',1]]
"bbbc" -> [['b',3],['c',1]]
"cccaa" -> [['a',2],['c',3]]
```

I could use search or scan and repeat for each possible letter, but is there a clean way of doing it?

This is as far as I got:

```
from pyparsing import *


def handleStuff(string, location, tokens):

        return [tokens[0][0], len(tokens[0])]


stype = Word("abc").setParseAction(handleStuff)
section =  ZeroOrMore(stype("stype"))


print section.parseString("abc").dump()
print section.parseString("aabcc").dump()
print section.parseString("bbaaa").dump()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't clear from your description whether the input characters could be mixed like "ababc", since in all your test cases, the letters were always grouped together.  If the letters *are* always grouped together, you could use this pyparsing code:

```
def makeExpr(ch):
    expr = Word(ch).setParseAction(lambda tokens: [ch,len(tokens[0])])
    return expr

expr = Each([Optional(makeExpr(ch)) for ch in "abc"])

for t in tests:
    print t,expr.parseString(t).asList()
```

The Each construct takes care of matching out of order, and Word(ch) handles the 1-to-n repetition.  The parse action takes care of converting the parsed tokens into the (character, count) tuples.

Comment: Yes the chars are grouped so this is perfect. Thanks for the solution and explanation. Loving pyparsing!

Answer (score 6):

One solution:

```
text = 'sufja srfjhvlasfjkhv lasjfvhslfjkv hlskjfvh slfkjvhslk'
print([(x,text.count(x)) for x in set(text)])
```

No pyparsing involved, but it seems like overkill.

Comment: I think I'll go with this by using pyparsing to pull the chunk and setParseAction to process it with this.  Still be interested to know if there is a pyparsing solution though!

Comment: Thanks for your solution - it's now been pipped by the pyparsing one, but thanks for your help and the very neat solution!

Answer (score 3):

I like [Lennart's one-line solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134416/pyparsing-where-order-of-tokens-in-unpredictable/2134640#2134640).

[Alex mentions another great option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134416/pyparsing-where-order-of-tokens-in-unpredictable/2134710#2134710) if you're using 3.1

Yet another option is [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mydict = defaultdict(int)
>>> for c in 'bbbc':
...   mydict[c] += 1
...
>>> mydict
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'c': 1, 'b': 3})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure-pyparsing approach, this feels about right:

```
from pyparsing import *

# lambda to define expressions
def makeExpr(ch):
    expr = Literal(ch).setResultsName(ch, listAllMatches=True)
    return expr

expr = OneOrMore(MatchFirst(makeExpr(c) for c in "abc"))
expr.setParseAction(lambda tokens: [[a,len(b)] for a,b in tokens.items()])


tests = """\
abc
bbbc
cccaa
""".splitlines()

for t in tests:
    print t,expr.parseString(t).asList()
```

Prints:

```
abc [['a', 1], ['c', 1], ['b', 1]]
bbbc [['c', 1], ['b', 3]]
cccaa [['a', 2], ['c', 3]]
```

But this starts to get into an obscure code area, since it relies on some of the more arcane features of pyparsing. In general, I like frequency counters that use defaultdict (haven't tried Counter yet), since it's pretty clear just what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

pyparsing apart -- in Python 3.1, [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.Counter) makes such counting tasks really easy.  A good version of `Counter` for Python 2 can be found [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/).

Comment: Like the Counter class - will keep that in mind for other things.  Thanks.