# Python: how to get sorted count of items in a list?

Tags: python

In Python, I've got a list of items like:

```
mylist = [a, a, a, a, b, b, b, d, d, d, c, c, e]
```

And I'd like to output something like:

```
a (4)
b (3)
d (3)
c (2)
e (1)
```

How can I output a count and leaderboard of items in a list? I'm not too bothered about efficiency, just any way that works :)

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried? there are loads of dupes on SO. Have you at least tried looking for them?

Comment: Yes I have. Sorry, I might be using the wrong search terms but I couldn't find anything that looked like what I needed. I have been experimenting but haven't got very far... apologies

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148480/can-pythons-list-comprehensions-ideally-do-the-equivalent-of-count-group/2148555#2148555

Comment: Is your listed always sorted?

Comment: Thanks @SilentGhost. I would never have found that from the search terms I was using! Hopefully this question will be useful to more newbie people searching in future.

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+frequency+count.  Specifically, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list.    Since it's exactly a year ago, and has almost the same sample data, this smells like homework.

Comment: sorry, didn't intend to create a duplicate - I really did search but couldn't find anything on the (newbie) search terms I was using!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def leaders(xs, top=10):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for x in xs:
        counts[x] += 1
    return sorted(counts.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[:top]
```

So this function uses a `defaultdict` to count the number of each entry in our list.  We then take each pair of the entry and its count and sort it in descending order according to the count.  We then take the `top` number of entries and return that.

So now we can say

```
>>> xs = list("jkl;fpfmklmcvuioqwerklmwqpmksdvjioh0-45mkofwk903rmiok0fmdfjsd")
>>> print leaders(xs)
[('k', 7), ('m', 7), ('f', 5), ('o', 4), ('0', 3), ('d', 3), ('i', 3), ('j', 3), ('l', 3), ('w', 3)]
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned `collections.Counter`. Assuming

```
import collections
mylist = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'e']
```

it's just a one liner:

```
print(collections.Counter(mylist).most_common())
```

which will print:

```
[('a', 4), ('b', 3), ('d', 3), ('c', 2), ('e', 1)]
```

Note that `Counter` is a subclass of `dict` with some useful methods for counting objects. Refer to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

A two-liner:

```
for count, elem in sorted(((mylist.count(e), e) for e in set(mylist)), reverse=True):
    print '%s (%d)' % (elem, count)
```

Comment: truly the best answer here