# python count items in list and keep their order of occurrance

Tags: python

Given: a list, such as l=[4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7]
Todo: get the count of an element and keep their occurrence order, e.g.:
[(4,4),(5,3),(6,1),(7,3)]

I could do it with:

```
tmpL    = [(i,l.count(i)) for i in l]
tmpS    = set()
cntList = [x for x in tmpL if x not in tmpS and not tmpS.add(x)]
```

But is there a better way? I have seen the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290962/python-how-to-get-sorted-count-of-items-in-a-list), but it sorts the counts and hence breaks the order.

Edit: performance is not an issue for the solution, preferable something built-in.

Comment: `itertools` is in the standard library.  It's not pre-imported, but it is bundled with python.  Is that still a problem?

Comment: Is this for some kind of run-length compression?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `groupby`:

```
>>> l = [4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,2,2]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [(i, l.count(i)) for i,_ in groupby(l)]
[(4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 1), (7, 3), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: but casting to set will change the order: >>> l=[7,7,7,7,7,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,6]                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>>> set(l)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
set([4, 5, 6, 7])

Comment: @lukmac Don't do it this way. `count` depends on the size of the whole list, not just the size of the group. Use Tim's method or the same general idea with `k, sum(1 for _ in g)` instead of `k, len(list(g))`.

Comment: @agf: I updated the answer as it was already accepted, but I'm now wondering what the normal procedure is. When a question is accepted, is it generally agreed upon to include (minor) fixes to improved upon it? Or should the asking person change the acceptance? Did I do the right thing?

Comment: It's fine to add fixes, but _not_ to change your answer to be exactly equivalent to an existing answer just because it's better. It doesn't matter whether the answer is accepted or not. The OP can change that if he wants.

Comment: @agf: it became indeed identical, shame on me for updating in a rush. Rolled back to the initial answer. To lukmac: see the discussion above; please reaccept the answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in itertools.groupby(l)]
[(4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 1), (7, 3)]
```

This keeps the order of the items and also allows repeated items:

```
>>> l=[4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,4,4,4,4,4]
>>> [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in itertools.groupby(l)]
[(4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 1), (7, 3), (4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 2.7, you can use the Counter from collections, which does exactly what you are looking to do:

http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: However, it doesn't keep the items in order (since it's implemented as a dictionary), which doesn't fulfill the OP's requirements.